# Graphic crash after Ubuntu 12.04 minor update

Tags: 12.04, graphics, acer, aspire-one

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix “The system is running in low-graphics mode” error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

My problem came after doing a normal packages update in 12.04 and then reboot to never been able to boot normally, it appear the "The system is running in low-graphics mode" window and then I tried to fix the problem reinstalling the gmd.

Now I'm reinstalling the whole system, from the USB boot it went everything as usual before that update. I just want to never have to reinstall Ubuntu in this way again. Any thoughts?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on an Acer Aspire One D255

Comment: Similar problem here!

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0):

On my Acer Aspire One 722, I observed the X-server freezing after a minor update to kernel:

```
3.2.0-27-generic-pae #43-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 6 15:06:05 UTC 2012 i686 athlon i386 GNU/Linux
```

This seems to be connected to the WLAN driver.

The X server restarts correctly after changing to the console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and killing the hanging X server. **However** this is only *a workaround, and not a fix.* As another suggestion: switching off WLAN before booting might work as well.